# Table visual is unintuitively aggregating my data

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am loading an Excel file, in which it has 43 rows, all the rows are identical. This is the only file I'm loading and there are no connections relationships in the model whatsoever.

When I plot my data into a table visual, and choose not to summarize any of my fields, Power BI still shows me one row. While if I change any of the field to do a count of it, it shows me correctly that I have 43 rows. I need to be able to see all the 43 rows in my table.

Why is Power BI summarizing my data even if I command it not to do so?

Am I missing something simple?

Input table as seen in Power BI data tab:
[image: Photos]

The visual I'm trying to create:
[image: Photos2]

Answer (score 0):

The table visual in *Power BI* behaves similar to a **Pivot Table** in *Excel*.

W/o an aggregation defined, the **"Values"** fields behave like **"Rows"** in a *Pivot Table* and you will only see distinct items or distinct item combinations. You have 43 identical records, hence it is represented as one row in the visual.

With an aggregation defined (Sum, Count, ...) the field behaves like **"Values"** in a *Pivot Table*, and you get the result of that aggregation, filtered by the distinct items/combinations to the left, which is again one row in your case.

If you just want to show all the records in a table visual, you'll have to make them unique. The easiest way to achieve that is by adding an index column in *PowerQuery* and then also showing that index in the table visual.

However, this is not exactly what *Power BI* is made for and you are probably better off by switching to something like *PowerPoint* instead.

*And btw., newer show sceenshots in stackoverflow, always provide sample data instead.*

Comment: Thank you for responding, apparently i misunderstood what the option don't summarize actually does, i know get that i need to have unique items and solved my problem with an index column, thank you for providing me and explanation, alright next time i'll provide some mock data, as the real data is confidential. Also thank you for the person that edited my question, i guess it looks better now and i hope you get paid for this ahah.